# Pass Data from OpenFileDialog between two windows with SIGNALs and SLOTs in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently developing a notepad in Qt.
I have two windows, one `splashscreen` where I show all the main buttons and the MainWindow where there is the TextEdit and all the other things.
On the `splashscreen`, I have a button, "Open File". I want to pass the text from a .txt file from the `splashscreen` to the MainWindow but my code doesn't work.

**splashscreen.h**

```
#ifndef SPLASHSCREEN_H
#define SPLASHSCREEN_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileDialog>

namespace Ui {
class splashscreen;
}

class splashscreen : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit splashscreen(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~splashscreen();

private slots:


    void on_newFile_btn_clicked();

    void on_about_btn_clicked();

    void onTextReturned();
signals:
    void newText(const QString &text);
private:
    Ui::splashscreen *ui;
};

#endif // SPLASHSCREEN_H
```

**splashscreen.cpp**

```
#include "splashscreen.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_splashscreen.h"
#include "about.h"

splashscreen::splashscreen(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::splashscreen)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //Disable Window Resizing
    this->setFixedSize(893, 594);

    //AppVersion
    QString version;
    version = "Version 0.4.0.40";

    //Set Splashscreen Background
    QPixmap splash_image;
    splash_image.load(":/Images/splashscreen.png");
    splash_image = splash_image.scaled(this->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);

    QPalette splash_palette;
    splash_palette.setBrush(QPalette::Window, splash_image);
    this->setPalette(splash_palette);

    //AppNamelbl Settings
    ui->appNamelbl->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color: aqua;}");

    //VersionCodelbl Settings
    ui->versionCode->setText(version);
    ui->versionCode->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color: white;}");

    //Copyrightlbl Settings
    ui->copyright_lbl->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color: white;}");

    //NewFile_btn Settings
    ui->newFile_btn->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {color: white;}");

    //OpenFile_btn Settings
    ui->openFile_btn->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {color: white;}");

    ui->appNameshw->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color: rgba(0,0,0,125);}");

    //About_btn Settings
    ui->about_btn->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {color: white;}");

    //Changelog Settings
    ui->changelog->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color: white;}");
    QFile changelog(QString(":/ChangeLog/changelog.txt"));
    if (changelog.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        while (!changelog.atEnd())
        {
            QString line = changelog.readLine();
            ui->changelog->setText(ui->changelog->text() + line);
        }
        changelog.close();
    }
    MainWindow mainwin;
    connect(ui->openFile_btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onTextReturned()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(newText(QString)), &mainwin, SLOT(onNewText(QString)));
}


splashscreen::~splashscreen()
{
    delete ui;
}


void splashscreen::on_newFile_btn_clicked()
{
    MainWindow *mainwin = new MainWindow();
    mainwin->show();
    this->close();
}


void splashscreen::on_about_btn_clicked()
{
    about *abt = new about;
    abt->exec();
}
void splashscreen::onTextReturned()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open a file"), "", tr("Text File (*.txt);; RichTextFormat File (*.rtf);; All Files (*)"));
    QFile file(fileName);
    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
    {
       QTextStream in (&file);
       QString text = in.readAll();
       MainWindow *mainwin = new MainWindow();
       emit newText(text);
       mainwin->show();
       file.close();
    }

}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>
#include <QGraphicsColorizeEffect>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QStandardPaths>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
public slots:
    void onNewText(const QString &text);
private slots:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *);
    void on_tabWidget_tabCloseRequested(int index);

    void on_newFile_clicked();
    QTextEdit* getTabTextEdit();

    void on_openFile_clicked();

    void on_save_clicked();

    void on_paste_clicked();

    void on_copy_clicked();

    void on_cut_clicked();

    void on_tabWidget_currentChanged(int index);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QString currentFile;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "splashscreen.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent),
      ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //Set MainWindow minimum size
    this->setMinimumHeight(440);
    this->setMinimumWidth(440);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::onNewText(const QString &text)
{
    ui->edit->setText(text);
}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *)
{
    ui->tabWidget->resize(this->width() + 2, this->height() - 87);
    ui->edit->resize(ui->tabWidget->width() - 6, ui->tabWidget->height() - 29);
}

void MainWindow::on_tabWidget_tabCloseRequested(int index)
{
    if (ui->tabWidget->count() > 1)
    {
        ui->tabWidget->removeTab(index);
    }

}

QTextEdit* MainWindow::getTabTextEdit()
{
    return qobject_cast <QTextEdit*>(ui->tabWidget->widget(ui->tabWidget->currentIndex()));
}

void MainWindow::on_newFile_clicked()
{
    ui->tabWidget->addTab(new QTextEdit(), QString("New Document " + QString::number(ui->tabWidget->count() + 1)));
    ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(ui->tabWidget->count() - 1);
    currentFile = "";
}

void MainWindow::on_openFile_clicked()
{
    QTextEdit *edit = getTabTextEdit();
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open a file"), "New Document", tr("Text File (*.txt);; RichTextFormat File (*.rtf);; All Files (*)"));
    QFile file(fileName);
    currentFile = fileName;
    if(ui->tabWidget->currentWidget() == ui->tab_1)
    {
        if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
        {
           ui->tabWidget->setTabText(ui->tabWidget->currentIndex(), file.fileName());
           QTextStream in (&file);
           QString text = in.readAll();
           ui->edit->setText(text);
           file.close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
        {
           ui->tabWidget->setTabText(ui->tabWidget->currentIndex(), file.fileName());
           QTextStream in (&file);
           QString text = in.readAll();
           edit->setText(text);
           file.close();
        }
    }
}


void MainWindow::on_save_clicked()
{
    QTextEdit *edit = getTabTextEdit();
    QString fileName;
    if (currentFile.isEmpty())
    {
        fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save a file"), "New Document", tr("Text File (*.txt);; RichTextFormat File (*.rtf);; All Files (*)"));
        currentFile = fileName;
    }
    else
    {
        fileName = currentFile;
    }
    QFile file(fileName);
    if(ui->tabWidget->currentWidget() == ui->tab_1)
    {
        if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
        {
            ui->tabWidget->setTabText(ui->tabWidget->currentIndex(), file.fileName());
            QTextStream out (&file);
            QString text = ui->edit->toPlainText();
            out << text;
            file.close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
        {
            ui->tabWidget->setTabText(ui->tabWidget->currentIndex(), file.fileName());
            QTextStream out (&file);
            QString text = edit->toPlainText();
            out << text;
            file.close();
        }
    }
}


void MainWindow::on_paste_clicked()
{
    QTextEdit *edit = getTabTextEdit();
    if(ui->tabWidget->currentWidget() == ui->tab_1)
    {
        ui->edit->paste();
    }
    else
    {
        edit->paste();
    }
}


void MainWindow::on_copy_clicked()
{
    QTextEdit *edit = getTabTextEdit();
    if(ui->tabWidget->currentWidget() == ui->tab_1)
    {
        ui->edit->copy();
    }
    else
    {
        edit->copy();
    }
}


void MainWindow::on_cut_clicked()
{
    QTextEdit *edit = getTabTextEdit();
    if(ui->tabWidget->currentWidget() == ui->tab_1)
    {
        ui->edit->cut();
    }
    else
    {
        edit->cut();
    }
}


void MainWindow::on_tabWidget_currentChanged(int index)
{
    currentFile = "";
    QString tabText = ui->tabWidget->tabText(index);
    if (!tabText.contains("New Document ", Qt::CaseSensitive))
    {
        currentFile = ui->tabWidget->tabText(index);
    }
}
```

Can you tell me what's the problem here?
Thank you.

Comment: The `MainWindow` instance used in the `connect` call is local to your `splashscreen` ctor.  As soon as the constructor completes the `MainWindow` will be destroyed with all connections being removed.

Comment: @G.M. how do I do it then?

Comment: I don't know enough about what you're trying to do to provide a real answer but you create `MainWindow` instances in both `splashscreen::on_newFile_btn_clicked` and `splashscreen::onTextReturned`.  Presumably the connection needs to be made to either one of both of those.

Comment: @G.M. Basically I have a splashscreen with a Open File button. This button searches for a TXT file selected by the user, then I wanna store the contento of the file in a QString and pass It to the MainWindow to show It on the textEdit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all , As I understand from your question , `splashscreen` class should load and show to users.
So in **main.cpp** function you should create an object from that class and show it to users .

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

#include "splashscreen.h"

int  main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication  a(argc, argv);
    splashscreen  w;

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

the second mistake is in this line : you put ;; instead of ;

in onTextReturned function replace it to this :

```
QString  fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open a file"), "", tr("Text File (*.txt); RichTextFormat File (*.rtf); All Files (*)"));
```

And your Important mistake is about creating an object from     MainWindow class .

I edit your code and Fixed your problem replace this :

**In splashscreen.h**

```
#ifndef SPLASHSCREEN_H
#define SPLASHSCREEN_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include "mainwindow.h"


namespace Ui
{
class splashscreen;
}

class splashscreen: public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit splashscreen(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    ~splashscreen();

private slots:
    void  on_newFile_btn_clicked();

    void  on_about_btn_clicked();

    void  onTextReturned();

signals:
    void  newText(const QString &text);

private:
    Ui::splashscreen *ui;
    MainWindow       *mainwin;
};

#endif // SPLASHSCREEN_H
```

In **splashscreen.cpp**

```
#include "splashscreen.h"
#include "ui_splashscreen.h"

#include <QTextStream>

splashscreen::splashscreen(QWidget *parent):
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::splashscreen)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    // Disable Window Resizing
    this->setFixedSize(893, 594);

    // AppVersion
    QString  version;
    version = "Version 0.4.0.40";

    mainwin = new MainWindow();


    // Set Splashscreen Background
    QPixmap  splash_image;
    splash_image.load(":/Images/splashscreen.png");
    splash_image = splash_image.scaled(this->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);

    QPalette  splash_palette;
    splash_palette.setBrush(QPalette::Window, splash_image);
    this->setPalette(splash_palette);


    // AppNamelbl Settings
    ui->appNamelbl->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color: aqua;}");

    // VersionCodelbl Settings
    ui->versionCode->setText(version);
    ui->versionCode->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color: white;}");

    // Copyrightlbl Settings
    ui->copyright_lbl->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color: white;}");

    // NewFile_btn Settings
    ui->newFile_btn->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {color: white;}");

    // OpenFile_btn Settings
    ui->openFile_btn->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {color: white;}");

    ui->appNameshw->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color: rgba(0,0,0,125);}");

    // About_btn Settings
    ui->about_btn->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {color: white;}");

    // Changelog Settings
    ui->changelog->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color: white;}");
    QFile  changelog(QString(":/ChangeLog/changelog.txt"));

    if (changelog.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        while (!changelog.atEnd())
        {
            QString  line = changelog.readLine();
            ui->changelog->setText(ui->changelog->text() + line);
        }

        changelog.close();
    }

    connect(ui->openFile_btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onTextReturned()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(newText(QString)), mainwin, SLOT(onNewText(QString)));
}

splashscreen::~splashscreen()
{
    delete ui;
}

void  splashscreen::on_newFile_btn_clicked()
{
    MainWindow *mainwin = new MainWindow();

    mainwin->show();
    this->close();
}

void  splashscreen::on_about_btn_clicked()
{
// about *abt = new about;

// abt->exec();
}

void  splashscreen::onTextReturned()
{
    QString  fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open a file"), "", tr("Text File (*.txt); RichTextFormat File (*.rtf); All Files (*)"));
    QFile    file(fileName);

    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
    {
        QTextStream  in(&file);
        QString      text = in.readAll();
        emit         newText(text);

        file.close();
        mainwin->show();
        this->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait what? I didn't understand.

Comment: Please put the .ui file in your question , I will fix it. or push your project in GitHub and put its link so I can fix it.

Comment: I cannot modify the question anymore, I'm gonna answer to it to put it

Comment: Try this and tell me did it fix your problem or not .

Comment: I already did this and it does not work.
The problem is that when I press the button, I would like to send it to the MainWindow which should show and display the text in a textEdit.

Comment: Okay, second error fixed. Btw I still have the initial files with the error you told me to fix

Comment: I edited my answer , `MainWindow       *mainwin; `object  should be defined in the header file and should create one object .